# How does a PC switch turn on a PC?

Tags: computers, motherboard, pc, cases

Here is my current level of understanding: virtually every PC case has a switch near the top to power on the PC. When the PC is off, pressing the switch once will power it on and the PC will begin booting. When the PC is already on, pressing the switch for a short period will usually cause the PC to go into a sleep state, and pressing and holding the switch will eventually cause the PC to return to the powered off state.

My question is: how is this actually implemented? What is the switch triggering whenever you press it for a short period versus a long period? There must be some standard that all PC case manufacturers know to follow to provide this feature. What kind of standards dictate this?

Comment: There is standby power that is always on if the PS is plugged to the wall.  You may see on some motherboards that you have leds on all the time, there is wake on lan the ethernet is on all the time and leds blinking there, etc.   only a percentage is "off", a part that is on is logic or software (some embedded mcu) is watching the switch.  If you have a server with a BMC the BMC is on and you can come in over ethernet or other interfaces to talk to the bmc to do things to the motherboard including turn it "on" or "off".

Comment: way back in the day, it did turn everything off.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)  that changed with the atx supply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, the computer is never really ***off*** unless you physically/electrically disconnect the power. Some part of the motherboard, a processor or bridge IC will be on that monitors the power button to act when it is pressed. The button is a simple momentary normally open switch. Press it and the IC it's connected to turns the rest of the system on/*off*. It is a soft power button instead of a hard, electronically disconnecting power switch. This soft button control of a low power mode sleeping IC is standard from high end computing to 10 dollar SOC, 3 dollar microcontrollers, to 5 cent ASICs.

The behavior of this soft power button is defined by the Advanced Configuration and Power
Interface Specification or ***ACPI***. A specific subsection of it is Operating System-directed configuration and Power Management (OSPM). Both are born from earlier standards. But you can see ACPI referenced in both Windows and Linux in various settings windows for power (or device manager/lspci)

Pretty much everyone uses the ACPI 1 button configuration for power & sleep in this day and age.

Comment: Please note that ACPI defines what the system should do when power button is pressd or how to interface the power management hardware in very high level of abstraction - it does not specify how the hardware shoud work as the hardware parts are defined out of scope by the ACPI standard. Comparable to everyone knowing that a light switch on a wall controls the ceiling light on and off, but how it is actually implemented depeds on situation, depending on if you have actual mains wiring between the switch and lamp, or an RF remote switch controlling a relay box, or DALI bus lighting control.

Comment: There is only one image which shows a high level hardware implementation : a pushbutton with one end grounded, and one end pulled up by a resistor, and this being connected to a power button input on a block called "ACPI chipset".

Answer (score 0):

The standard defining the power button functionality **electrically** is really an intel guideline, "Front Panel I/O Connectivity Design Guide", in the section "Front Panel Legacy I/O", e.g. in [version 1.3](http://libgen.rs/search.php?req=C7780D00F3E7E048BBAA5E6A0F2DBA91&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=md5) of that reference.

The switch just connects two cables, which go to the motherboard. The motherboard, when the PC is off, still receives standby power from the power supply, and reacts to the shorting of these two wires by initiating the boot sequence (typically, that is. This is what the firmware decides to do).

When the PC is already running, the shorting instead causes the motherboard firmware to emit an ACPI hardware event, which gets handled by the operating system, in an arbitrary way (you can configure what happens, depending on your OS).

The long press *might* be handled by the firmware of the motherboard, and again, that firmware could do arbitrary things, but in consumer hardware, typically just causes a hard power off.

Just to give you an idea of how old this is: the intel guidelines are from 2000, but already describe the front panel button as "legacy I/O" and ACPI as standard way of the motherboard firmware to exchange power-related information with your operating system, is from 1996; you should really find a lot of information out there.

Comment: Do you have another source for the link? This one is prompting me to sign in to view the webpage.

Comment: @DavidD. working on that

Comment: @DavidD. I found a similar document https://t1.daumcdn.net/blogfile/fs7/1_19_19_19_0KHWN_IMAGE_0_0.pdf?original&filename=A2928604-005.pdf?download

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is simply a guideline, and quite necessary after Intel or someone else decided it would be nice to have also front panel audio connectors. The other stuff like buttons and LEDs are not defined here, but just collected how most motherboards work, even changing the button pull-up and pull-up voltage in different revisions of that document. Long before this many motherboards simply had approximately 330 ohm resistors for LEDs and some pull-up resistors to some suitable voltage on power and standby buttons.

Comment: @Justme jep, but as far as I can tell, it's the closest to a standard that exists in that field.

Answer (score -2):

The button is just a button. The button or case do nothing special. The button is just directly connected to motherboard with wires, so it's up to the motherboard how it reacts to the two button wires.

An the power button directly does not control any power, it is just electronically sending a signal to standby-powered motherboard section or IC responsible of monitoring if the button is pushed or not. The IC will either really control the main power supply to start or stop or, in case of power being on, notifying the OS about button being pushed first.

So it's anyway not much different from a power button on a TV, or on a TV remote. Standby powered section gets signals if the rest of the main system should be turned on or off, except TV remotes may use infrared or radio waves to notify about button pushes.

The pushbutton being pressed or not is monitored by a section of the motherboard which is powered from the stanby supply. This sections is usually inside one of the large chipset ICs, that need stanby supply anyway, for running the real-time clock, when only standby power is available.

So the button is usually connected with ground and a signal that gets grounded when the button is pushed, and the signal is pulled up to supply voltage with a resistor when the button is not pushed.

This signal then goes into an IC that monitors the pushbutton state and keeps state of the current power state. The button signal is noisy so it is likely first debounced in hardware.

If power is off, a falling edge turns power on. If power is on, a falling edge triggers another part that results in sending a signal or some sort of notification to the CPU running the OS that the button has been pushed. If you keep pushing the power button, a counter keeps tracking how long it is pushed and if it has been pushed long enough, the power supply is simply turnd off. If the OS did shut down it can also send a signal or some sort of notification to the circuit to turn the power supply off.